# HTML CSS and jquery: Menu with Horizontal Submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am work on this HTMl, CSS and maybe some javascript. I am trying create a menu with submenu, so when I hover on my menu, I want the submenu to display below with absolute position. My main menu is work, but the submenu is not work like the way I want it to. When I hover on my menu, the submenu does show, but only the first word is showing and the rest of the content are not showing. Below I image and code and also what I want to achieve. Any help, please?

**Image of Main menu**
[image]

**On hover, this is what I am getting for my submenu**
[image]

**And this is what I am trying to achieve**
[image]

**Below is the HTML code and CSS**

```css
body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }

    .container-fluid.wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .navbar {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #333;
     }

    .navbar a {
     float: left;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     }

     .nav-item {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline;
     overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     }
    .nav-item .dropdown-content {
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100% !important;
    }

   
    .nav-item .dropdown-content a {
     float: left;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline;
    }

    .nav-item .dropdown-content a{
     display: inline !important;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
     color: #FFF;
     background: red !important;}
     .nav-item:hover a{
      color: #FFF !important;
      }

     .navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-content {
       display: block;
      }

      .navbar-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
       text-decoration: underline;
      }

      .navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
        background-color: red;
       }

      .subnav-content a:hover {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: black;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper p-0">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Women <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Computer Science</a>
                  <a href="#">Math</a>
                  <a href="#">Other</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Children</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Man</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="conta-fluid">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change a few things:

You've put `position: relative` on the `dropdown` container which has the buttons. This makes that when you absolutely position the menu it will get clipped by the container. So I've deleted this from

```
.dropdown {
  float: left;
}
```

Furthermore I've edited the menu:

```
.nav-item .dropdown-content {
  ...
  background-color: red;
  top: 80px;
}
```

Inserted a red color so it sticks out against the background, like the example and gave it an absolute position on the page of `80px` from the top.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;

}

.nav-item .dropdown-content {
  background-color: red;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-content a {
  display: inline !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: red !important;
}

.nav-item:hover a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper p-0">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Women <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Computer Science</a>
                  <a href="#">Math</a>
                  <a href="#">Other</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Children</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Man</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="conta-fluid">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```